# Enable Do Not Disturb While Driving" automatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 5S, recently successfully installed iOS11. In the "Do Not Disturb While Driving" Option under Activate, I only get option to enable "When Connected to Car Bluetooth" and "Manually" but not "Automatically" which I can see by many tutorials and help sheets (and from the "Learn More" section from the iPhone itself" should be an option. Why is it not appearing?

Comment: it may be that the 5s doesn't support the automatic option.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks dwightk. It looks like you're right. I just watched this video on iOS 11 for the iPhone 5S. When they came to the Do Not Disturb While Driving feature (@ 3:55), the shot didn't show the "automatically" option either, just the two mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, here is the video:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3A47dGh6aY